# Jquery - Using Touch Swipe to Check Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, swipe, touchscreen

So I have a CSS3 slides setup with radio buttons to trigger the next slide. I want to be able to add touch/swipe to it for tablets and phones (i.e. swipe left and and the next radio gets checked).

The jQuery I'm trying to use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cover").swipeleft(function(event){
            $('input:radio[class=slide_2]').attr("checked", true);
    });
    $("#cover2").swiperight(function(event){
        $('input:radio[class=slide_1]').attr("checked", true);
    });
    $("#cover2").swipeleft(function(event){
        $('input:radio[class=slide_3]').attr("checked", true);
    });
    $("#ingredients").swiperight(function(event){
        $('input:radio[class=slide_2]').attr("checked", true);
    });
    $("#ingredients").swipeleft(function(event){
        $('input:radio[class=slide_4]').attr("checked", true);
    });
    $("#directions").swiperight(function(event){
        $('input:radio[class=slide_3]').attr("checked", true);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hakarune/ZsrdP/1/  Here's the whole setup and my jQuery, but it doesn't work at all. Anyone have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: New update, **[Blaise Rienzo](https://plus.google.com/117008506972458525056/posts)** on G+ was able to make a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hakarune/xnPdx/2/)** that works. He Included jQueryMobile, added `section{height: 100%}` to the CSS, changed `.attr` to `.prop`... I changed it so the swipe goes off the slide div instead and it worked in the fiddle. But as soon as I set it up as an actual page, it doesn't work anymore [DEMO](https://googledrive.com/host/0B5Ubvdjb2dQUbERvaHpUTkdUVkk/demo.html) is there something wrong?

Comment: There were errors returned for it not being https serve, tried https and local on the site, adding `jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js` seems to cause the page to go blank, but does not produce errors....

Comment: It turns out it was related to `jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js` as soon as I changed it to `jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js` via https host it worked.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a library like [hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/)
and your code would be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#cover").hammer().on(swipeleft, function(event){
        $('input:radio[class=slide_2]').attr("checked", true);
});
$("#cover2").hammer().on(swiperight, function(event){
    $('input:radio[class=slide_1]').attr("checked", true);
});
$("#cover2").hammer().on(swipeleft, function(event){
    $('input:radio[class=slide_3]').attr("checked", true);
});
$("#ingredients").hammer().on(swiperight, function(event){
    $('input:radio[class=slide_2]').attr("checked", true);
});
$("#ingredients").hammer().on(swipeleft, function(event){
    $('input:radio[class=slide_4]').attr("checked", true);
});
$("#directions").hammer().on(swiperight, function(event){
    $('input:radio[class=slide_3]').attr("checked", true);
});
});
```

Comment: Just tested it out **[here](https://googledrive.com/host/0B5Ubvdjb2dQUbERvaHpUTkdUVkk/demo.html)** and it doesn't work....Any ideas?

Comment: make sure you called the jquery hammer library in your <head> tag and you could call your input with only class selector since every one has different class, and remove true from brackets like this: $('.slide_2').attr("checked");